# how to specify parameter id from client js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

lets say I have

```
app.get("/msg/:id", (req, res) => {
    const plan = db.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    res.send(plan);
});
```

How do I get/specify from the client javascript the id i want to be returned when i click a button for example,

Thank you

Comment: There is href link like http://domain:port/msg/23

Comment: can you post your server and client code

Comment: @Dipakchavda if i have a GET request through the client js how do i specify the id of what to be returned